# Configuring OpenTelemetry ContextStorage in Java

Tags: java, vert.x, open-telemetry

I'm having an issue with OpenTelemetry in Java.

I am in the process of transitioning from Opentracing to OpenTelemetry on a library that is using vert.x. I have included *vertx-opentelemetry* library, which includes *VertxContextStorageProvider* class.

This class is then set as the default context storage.

My issue is that this relies on vert.x being initialized, and breaks my tests which are testing certain parts that just don't need to initialize vert.x to be tested.

I saw that I can set a system property to enforce OpenTelemetry to load the default context provider. But, honestly, that seems like an overkill if I need to do it in all of my test classes.

Is there any way I can use the default (ThreadLocalContextStorage) implementation?

I tried creating my own implementation of context provider, but the ClassLoader didn't load it, and still loaded only the vert.x implementation.